# ClickOnce Security Warning on the EXE

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, clickonce, code-signing

I have a ClickOnce project deploying, signed with Comodo (Sectigo) Code Signing. However, even with the code signing, the .exe that's updated gets flagged with a security warning upon program launch. See the image below for a screenshot.

[image]

After investigation, it is caused by the .exe blocked by Windows. See the image below for a screenshot.

[image]

I can unblock it manually, but when there's an update downloaded via ClickOnce, the .exe is blocked again.

I've searched online for a solution, but all solutions tell me to edit the registry. I want to look for a solution to fix this without editing the registry on each of my client's machines. What makes my .exe different from any other .exe file downloaded from somewhere else?

Any help will be fantastic!

Thank you

**Additional Information**

ClickOnce manifests signed (See image below for screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Is the Clickonce manifest signed?

Comment: @Charlieface, yes, it is signed.

Comment: Will it work if add the certificate to trusted publishers?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT not sure, but even if it works, it is not practical because I can't ask our users to install certificate before installing my software